# iis - cname - start page when using domain and content using www.domain

Tags: iis, windows-server-2008, iis-7.5, cname-record

I configured a domain on IIS 7.5 with windows 2008 r2 and put an `index.html` file on the `inetpub/wwwroot/domain` folder.

When I browse the webpage currently I´m receiving two different pages:

- using `domain.com` I receive the `iistart.htm` welcome page.
- using `www.domain.com` I receive the `index.html` file I created.

I create the CNAME pointing `www.domain.com` to `domain.com` in order to serve content using both addresses´s.

ADDITIONAL INFO:

When using `domain.com` it points to the Default Web Site created by default by IIS 7.5. I realized about that when I stopped that site.

Comment: ok I found the reason. despite that I created the CNAME on the DNS area, IIS needs to set up bindings pointing to www.domain.com and domain.com for each website. brgds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason. Despite creating the CNAME record in my DNS, IIS needs bindings for both `www.domain.com` *and* `domain.com` for each website.